# Sqlite table returning limited number of entries

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this android application that has an sqlite table of 3 million records, when I search by on "a" as parameter (which is found in most records of the table) the returned list is always of size 20,000.

why is that?

Comment: *why is that?* it's because of your code

Comment: If you don't wana such comments please learn how to ask ... you have problem with your code and you didn't post it, that's make your question off-topic: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Answer (score 0):

Solved, apparently the previous developer has put a limitation on the size